# Transparent border shows 3D effect

Tags: css

I am assigning two different classes on a div, for when it is selected. I gave the selected div a `2px solid blue border` and gave the unselected one a `2px transparent` one so it doesn't transform the dimensions of the div when it is selected.

```
.recipe-card-container-selected {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: linear-gradient(254deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(51, 64, 93, 1) 85%);
  box-shadow: 4px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid $primary-blue;
}

.recipe-card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: linear-gradient(215deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(51, 64, 93, 1) 85%);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 4px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

[image]

I get this weird 3D border effect with the transparency because I used a linear gradient. Any idea on how could I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Just set your element's `box-sizing` to `border-box` and remove the transparent border. This allows the overall box model's size to absorb values like border and padding, rather than tacking it on to the calculation.

```
.recipe-card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: linear-gradient(215deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(51, 64, 93, 1) 85%);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 4px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

If the weird 3D effect persists, it's likely your box-shadow. Also, if this box sizing seems most practical to you, set global box sizing with this:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: ```box-sizing``` only works if you give your div a fixed height and width. Which is not something really practical in my case...

Comment: Hi @Philx94, not sure what you mean by that? `border-box` works perfectly fine on variable widths and heights. Please see this example: https://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/ExYBQva

Comment: Hi @misterManSam. What I meant is that if your div has no with or height property, ```border-box``` won't work. I also validated this on the codepen. Thanks